# ng for loop into other ng for loop not work Angular

Tags: html, angular, ngfor

I want to display the model array list using ngFor into other ng for but I am having a series of problems since apparently the properties of my model are not recognized from the HTML. But Something very very strange happens, I hope you can help me

My interface:

```
export interface ShoppingCar {
  username: string;
  items: ItemShoppingCar[];
}

export interface ItemShoppingCar {
  description: string;
  price: number;
}
```

My ts:

```
export class ShoppingComponent implements OnInit {

  shopItems: ShoppingCar[] = [];

  constructor(private shoppingService: ShoppingService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.shoppingService.all()
    .subscribe(
        (response) => {
            if(response.success) {
                this.shopItems = response.Result;
            }
        }
    );
  }
}
```

My html:

```
<div *ngFor="let shopItem of shopItems">
 <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">{{ shopItem.username }}</h5>
      <hr>
      <div class="flex-items" *ngFor="item of shopItem.items">
        <span class="descripcion-item">{{ item.description }}</span>
        <span class="price-item">{{ item.price }}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

compilation errors

> error TS2339: Property 'item' does not exist on type 'ShoppingComponent '.

```
56              <span class="descripcion-item">{{ item.description }}</span>
```

> error TS2339: Property 'item' does not exist on type 'ShoppingComponent '.

```
56               <span class="price-item">{{ item.price }}</span>
```

When I save the file of my models with ctrl + s, there if it compiles, however when executing it throws me another error because apparently, it does not recognize the properties of the models of my second ngFor loop.

```
core.js:10069 NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.
logUnknownPropertyError @ core.js:10069
5core.js:6157 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of undefined
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you forgot a `let` in the nested loop. I think that it should be `*ngFor="`**`let`**`item of shopItem.items"`:

```
<div *ngFor="let shopItem of shopItems">
 <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">{{ shopItem.username }}</h5>
      <hr>
      <!-- here we go: -->
      <div class="flex-items" *ngFor="let item of shopItem.items">
        <span class="descripcion-item">{{ item.description }}</span>
        <span class="price-item">{{ item.price }}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This one should fix your error. It explained why the property 'item' does not exist and why you cant read property 'description' of item.